# SOIL_load_image() returns null

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, soil

**ANSWER**

After using `SOIL_last_result()`, as `dcook` had suggested, I found out two things:

1) It couldn't find the image, as `PaulMcKenzie` said, so my working directory was indeed incorrect as `genpfault` mentioned.

2) After I set a full path, it mentioned that my jpeg format(progressive), was not supported. I set the image to the standard jpeg format and it worked.

Thanks for the help!

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am currently trying to load an image using SOIL to use with OpenGL. However, it seems to fail to properly load the image as the variable it is assigned to ends up being null. I've tried looking at [this](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/185838-SOIL_load_image()-returns-null) but it seems the guy just put the wrong layout position when he set the attribute. I have it check for errors(`glGetError()`) after every line but I omitted that here for readability.

The OpenGL error occurs after `glTexImage2D()` with a `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. This is more than likely because `imgWidth`/`imgHeight` are bigger than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` due to the null image.

**Output:**

```
null: 1
Max size: 3379
Width: 4298563
Height: 2686488
Obj: 1
GL_INVALID_VALUE - ../src/polygon.cpp:222
```

**Code:**

```
    // Generate the texture object and binds it.
    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

    // Texture image data
    int imgWidth, imgHeight;

    // Load the texture image.
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("potato.jpg",
                  &imgWidth,
                  &imgHeight,
                  0,
                  SOIL_LOAD_RGB);


    std::cout << "null: " << !image << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max size: " << GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Width: " <<  imgWidth << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Height: " << imgHeight << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Obj: " << m_texture << std::endl;

    // Generate the texture to the currently bound texture object.
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
         0,
         GL_RGB,
         imgWidth,
         imgHeight,
         0,
         GL_RGB,
         GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
         image);

    // Generate the mipmap to the currently bound texture object.
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Unbind and free image data.
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Let me know if any more data is needed. Thanks!

**EDIT 1:** Yes, the image is in the correct location:
[image: bin directory]

Also, I tried using a full path, it did not help.

Comment: Is your [`pwd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) where your program is assuming it is?

Comment: Maybe the file `potato.jpg` cannot be found?  Give a full path and retry.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried using a full path, it was to no avail.

Comment: @genpfault It should be in the same directory as the executable. However, I have tried setting the working directory manually(through PowerShell) and it did not work.

Comment: I don't know much about SOIL, but when I had used it for texture mapping, I had used an unsigned int to store my texture. And the whole thing looked like `unsigned int texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
        (
        "textures/texture0.jpg",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
        );`
See if this helps your case.

Comment: And here's my code for reference: https://github.com/ranveeraggarwal/transformer/blob/master/gl_framework.cpp

Comment: @MrSnappingTurtle: from that screenshot, one cannot even deduce that "potato.jpg" is the correct file name. It might as well be "potato.jpeg" or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems to be an issue with SOIL rather than GL, check the last SOIL error with `SOIL_last_result` after calling `SOIL_load_image`. This should give you a better clue as to what's actually going wrong.

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution was to set full path to file, like

```
C:/TestProjectsCPP/OpenGLTutorials/OpenGLTutorials/res/images/image1.jpg
```

After this image was loaded and shown.